# HEX where clause in Postgre

Tags: postgresql

I'm new in postgreSQL

how to do this

```
select * from table_abc where table_abc.a>=7a and table_abc.b<=7a
```

all value is HEX in column a, b and input value

Thanks

EDIT :

### table_abc

```
a bytea
b bytea
c text
```

Comment: Why are you storing col_abc as a combined a, b, and c? You won't be able to index the data that way. There's no such thing as a subcolumn like you're looking for, although I suppose you could do some bitshifting. That would be very slow if you had a large amount of data. What problem are you trying to solve, exactly?

Comment: @Jordan: PostgreSQL does support [composite types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rowtypes.html) so that sort of syntax is possible.

Comment: @mu: thanks, I had forgotten about those. I'm still very curious as to what exactly the point of this is, and why bother to store in hex if you can just convert and store as native int.

Comment: @jordan : owh sory, i mistyped. col_abc just an example name of table
may be i should write table_abc :D

Comment: I don't know what you mean when you say that "all value is HEX in field a, b". What type are the columns? Can you include the table's schema to help clear up the confusion?

Comment: @mu is too short : a and b is bytea

Answer (score 1):

Careful, here.  In Postgres, `bytea` is a *byte array*.  You look like you want to store a single byte in those columns.

I don't see a single-byte type in the list of datatypes at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype.html.

You can go with an integer type.  For example, when I say this:

```
select x'7A'::integer
```

I get 122.

If you intend to store a single byte in these columns and write your queries with hex values, then I suggest you make the columns integers and query like this:

```
select * from table_abc where table_abc.a>=x'7a'::integer and table_abc.b<=x'7a'::integer
```